# The Gardener's Route

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, logic-grid

Tell me the method for solving such grid problems in detail.

[image: Question 6.]

I need a solution for The Gardener's problem.Tell me any method to construct the grid.

Comment: Why do you *need* a solution? Could you please tidy up the question, crop the image and incorporate the text into the question. You should also cite the source of the puzzle. Thanks.

Comment: @M Oehm The source is Moscow Puzzles.But in solution they show only one probable route.Please guide me for such kind of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather easy.

> There are two gaps in the walls, and obviously you have to go through one and back through the other. Apart from that, just zig-zag across all the squares.
>
> [image]

Comment: you dont have to use one gap actually.

Comment: @Oray: If you want to visit all cells and return to the starred cell, you'll have to pass both gaps. I you just want to visit all cells, one gap is enough.

Comment: @MOehm I did not notice he had to return back :)